# Why does macvtap create an interface?

Tags: linux, networking

As opposed to macvlan, when you create it you only get one extra interface, say, macvlan@parent_ethX that you can move to another net namespace. However, when you create macvtap you get not only the /dev/tapX but also macvtapX@parent_ethX. What's the purpose of this interface? isn't /dev/tapX already enough?

In the case of a regular tap device I can understand that you want to connect /dev/tapX to a vpn daemon and use the ip on the tap interface as default for all other processes. But it confuses me on macvtap

Comment: ...if I had to guess, probably to stay compatible with programs that use tun/tap ioctl APIs that are based on interface name.